# Custom Presence with UCMA 2.0 and OCS 2007

Tags: ocs, ucma

I have recently started working with Unified Communication Managed API 2.0 (UCMA) and Office Communication Server(OCS) 2007. I have a need in my app that I have to create custom presence for my users? Has anyone of you guys done this before and can point me in right direction?

There is not much documentation out there regarding this, so I am struggling here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got the Answer.
We have to execute couple of stored procedures on OCS side to add those custom presence there. 
Then we can publish to those presence just like every other ones!

Answer (score 1):

I've not done any work with the 2.0 API yet, but these posts may be useful for you:

[Joe Calev's Weblog](http://blogs.msdn.com/jcalev/archive/tags/2.0/default.aspx) (apologies if you've already seen them)

Also, there might be some useful nuggets in here (its V1 but some of the concepts are similar):

[UCMA 1.0 Sample app](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=16303459-DD75-451F-B7C0-FB2EB0D9A84A&displaylang=en)